# Trying to remove character EM DASH "—" (â€”) in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I got this stubborn EM DASH character that I'm trying to remove using regex, but for some reason I can't get it to work. This is the code I'm using.

```
editedSource = re.sub(r'\u2014','',str(source))
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty sure I got the right character code. Here's the character:

> —

and it shows up like

> â€”

.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: str converts something to a byte-string. You probably want to do the substitution on a *unicode* string.

Comment: Handling unicode with Python 2 is tricky. Make sure `type(source)` is `unicode`, then don't use `str` on it. In Python 2, str is more like a byte array than a character string, so what you're seeing there are UTF-8 bytes printed as extended ASCII.

Answer (score 5):

Prep-end regex pattern with `u` to tell regex engine that parse the unicode and do not try to cast `unicode` into `str`.

```
>>>source = u'hello\u2014world'
>>>re.sub(ur'\u2014','',source)
>>>u'helloworld'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> source = u'hello\u2014world'
>>> print source
hello—world
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(u'\u2014','',source)
u'helloworld'
```

Note, you can remove/replace individual unicode characters more efficiently with a mapping like this

```
>>> source.translate({0x2014: None})
u'helloworld'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in Python 3:

```
editedSource = re.sub('\â€”','',str(source))
```