# Removing special punctuation

Tags: python, string, nlp, punctuation

In my text, I have special characters such as em dashes and guillemets (pointed quotation marks) which are not removed by omitting `string.punctuation`

What is the correct way to remove this type of punctuation from strings in Python 3?

```
import string

mystring = ' »De fleste – digitale –'
mystring.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
' »De fleste – digitale –'
```

Comment: Does [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930767/trying-to-remove-character-em-dash-â€-in-python-using-regex) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import itertools as it

mystring = ' »De fleste – digitale –'
newstring = ''
mystring = newstring.join(it.filterfalse(lambda x: x in '»–', mystring))
print(mystring) #=> " De fleste  digitale"
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple solution:

```py
    mystring = ' »De fleste – digitale –'
    print(''.join(x for x in mystring if x not in ['»', '–', '?', '!', '«']))
```

you can add whatever you want to omit to the list inside the `.join()` function